# error: no member named 'isnan' in namespace 'std' using std::isnan;

Tags: c++, macos, point-cloud-library

I am compiling a Point Cloud Library project on Mac and 
I get the following error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
```

Here are the exact steps I have taken to compile the project

```
$> brew update
$> brew tap brewsci/science
$> brew options pcl
$> brew install pcl
$> cd ~
$> git clone https://github.com/udacity/SFND_Lidar_Obstacle_Detection.git
$> cd SFND_Lidar_Obstacle_Detection
$> mkdir build && cd build
$> cmake ..
$> make
```

I tried changing the file given in that address from include to include  but it wouldn't allow me because the file is read only.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

add_definitions(-std=c++17)

set(CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "${CXX_FLAGS}")

project(playback)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
list(REMOVE_ITEM PCL_LIBRARIES "vtkproj4")


add_executable (environment src/environment.cpp src/render/render.cpp src/processPointClouds.cpp)
target_link_libraries (environment ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I have tried compiling with clang++ and g++ but didn't see any difference!

Comment: Check the file and make sure they `#include <cmath>` in the file.

Comment: according to the compiler the issue is in ```/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;```-- I got many errors of this sort.

Comment: I tried changing the file given in that address from include<math.h> to include <cmath> but it wouldn't allow me because the file is read only.

Comment: Could you build a [mcve]? Often you won't even have to post it here. You'll get about half of the example built and see the error for yourself.

Comment: Did you pass an argument to std::isnan(myFloat)?

Comment: I provided the exact steps I took for compilation.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2601

Comment: Thank you @simon I deleted Xcode and it magically worked.